# Nginx ciphers settings

Tags: nginx, encryption

I am trying to understand ciphers settings in nginx.

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; #What TLS types that are supported
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on; #Use the type that the server prefers
ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+RC4:EDH+aRSA:EECDH:RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS;
```

But when it comes to the ssl_ciphers I don't understand the string. Like for example, what does `'EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM'`,`'EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256'` and `'!PSK:!SRP:!DSS'` mean?

Does the data that is transferred between the client and server go through a specific encryption chain, like for example `'EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256'`?

Thanks for any help and guidance!

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://scotthelme.co.uk/https-cheat-sheet/) gives some useful information.

Here's a piece from the page that gives you a pretty good idea what it's doing

**Cipher Suites**
Choosing ciphers suites can be difficult and their names may look complex but they can be easily broken down into their components. Take the following suite:

```
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

The components are:

```
TLS - the protocol used
ECDHE - the key exchange mechanism
ECDSA - the algorithm of the authentication key
AES - the symmetric encryption algorithm
128 - the key size of the above
GCM - the mode of the above
SHA256 - the MAC used by the algorithm
```